# Append Img Src on Input Change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a form where when a user types into an input box, the input box changes the ending of the src of my image (which is an API image).

So the image code looks like this:

```
<img src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&size=100x100" />
```

I need the input from the textbox to go after the data=   and before the &size=100x100

I have tried a couple of ways of accomplishing this but haven't quite got it:

```
$(function() {
                        $('#linktextbox').onchange( function() {
                            window.location = document.getElementById('baseUrl').attr('href') + '/' + $('#linktextbox').val();
                            return false;
                        });
                    });
```

I have also tried:

```
var link = document.getElementById("baseUrl");
    link.href = "http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data="+document.getElementById('linktextbox')+"&size=100x100"
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: maybe u might also need to post those couple of ways u tried

Comment: Show what you've tried so we can get an idea of what you've attempted yourself

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile  I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this.

Obviously you need an input and something to confirm the user action like the button I added.

edit: In order to not abuse the server that generates the image I have deliberately chosen not to use a keyUp event.

When you click the button the small piece of Javascript updates the src of the image tag.

I used IDs to identify the HTML elements, but there are a number of different ways to find a specific element.

```js
function updateQR (){
   document.getElementById('image').src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=" + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('textInput').value) + "&size=100x100";

}
```

```html
    <input id="textInput" type="text">
    <br>
    <button onclick="updateQR()">Update QR code</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    <img id="image" src="" />
```

Comment: You might want to do a `encodeURIComponent()` on your textInput data.

Answer (score 1):

Here the code in plain JavaScript

```js
function updateQr(ele){
  document.getElementById("qr").src = "https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data="+encodeURIComponent(ele.value)+"&size=100x100/";
}
```

```html
<input type="textbox" value="HelloWorld" onKeyUp="updateQr(this)"/><br/><br/>
<img id="qr" src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&size=100x100/">
```